# Как задать индекс элементам массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы, объекты

У меня  имеется массив  содержащий объекты,  у каждого объекта есть есть ключ - уникальный  id.  Нужно  написать счетчик  для  ключа id. Каждый  раз руками с проставлять становится всё сложнее, объектов накопилось много.

Вот код:

```
     var markersCategory =
            {
                "category1":[
                {id:'1', latLng:[54.5839516,-1.2529945], address1:"Info"},
                {id:'2', latLng:[52.9719395,-1.1543138], address1:"Info"},
                {id:'3', latLng:[53.3942127,-2.8886705], address1:"Info"}
                ....
                ]
            };
```

> Я  так понимаю, что нужно  написать какой-то простенький цикл, может 
>   кто подскажет как?)

Заранее благодарю за ответы!

Comment: Поясните для каких целей это нужно. У каждого элемента массива и так есть уникальный индекс

Comment: @yolosora   много  объектов,  часто  допускаю ошибки при редактировании  этого массива. Возникла необходимость автоматизировать этот процесс с id. 
Буду благодарен  за  любой совет, спасибо!

Comment: Все еще не понимаю зачем это нужно. `id` нужны для того чтобы удобнее было манипулировать с данными в коде? Тогда если вы их будете прописывать программно, то в коде вы результата не увидите и вообще у вас в таком случае проблема в том, что все слишком "захардкожено"

Comment: похоже на XY-проблему...

Comment: @yolosora я  полностью с Вами согласен :) 
 Но  тут ситуация  требует, таких  жертв.  целей день  в ресерче

Comment: Ну можно читать js-файл как текст, регулярками находить нужные элементы и прописывать туда `id`, другого решения не вижу. Я бы настоятельно рекомендовал переделывать решение целиком если оно требует многоуровнего отстраивания костылей.

Comment: Если Ваш массив, в реальности имеет такие же `id` как и в примере, то очередной `id` равен `category1.length+1`. Определяйте это число в момент добавления элемента в массив.